# Using Dropdown menu for One to One relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I plan on making a genotype calculator in the future. I intend for this calculator to eventually be able to compute the following from a pairing: probability of color listing all possibilities, genotype.

I am wanting to make a dropdown menu/text field combination on a very simple webpage to learn how it works so that I can continue my project and hopefully meet this goal. I have searched and tried to figure this out, but I am pretty lost. Currently in my database I have a table called "colors" with the following schema:

```
id
angora_color
genotype
created_at
updated_at
```

I do not intend for users to be able to add data to this form. I want them to be able to select a color from the dropdown box, and get the genotype in a text field below it.

My code so far is as follows:

```
    class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :genotype
end

    class Genotype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :color
end

index.html.erb:
<h2>Placeholder for Genotype List..</h2>

    class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you only want a has_one relationship? Wouldn't a Genotype have many colors? and Colors can be part of many Genotypes?

You also can't have both models declare has_one. One model has to belong to the other. And the one that `belongs_to` should have the foreign key as `<model_name>_id` e.g. `genotype_id`. In your table you only put `genotype`. Rails looks for that `_id`.

What may be better here is to use [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). Create a join model such as genotypes_colors:

```
rails g model GenotypesColor genotype_id:integer color_id:integer
```

Then change your code to look like:

```
class Genotype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genotypes_colors
  has_many :colors, through: :genotypes_colors
end

class GenotypesColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :genotype
  belongs_to :color
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genotypes_colors
  has_many :genotypes, through: :genotypes_colors
end
```

Now you can correctly relate a Genotype to its Colors. You can use fields_for in either model's forms to create the genotypes_color association that will relate a Genotype to any Color or vice versa. If this sounds about right let me know and I can further help on how to do the forms.

Comment: Right now with the way I have the csv built, one color corresponds to one genotype. Parts of a genotype might match up to a line of colors, eg "Gold Tipped ___" starts out "A_B_" but depending on the rest of the color it changes. Would that still satisfy a has_many relationship model?

Comment: Can you post the schema to both your colors and genotypes tables plz?

Comment: Right now it's one single table. The schema is listed in the OP. Should I split it up?

Comment: Yea you defined 2 ActiveRecord models in your OP. You need two separate tables in order to have any relations between them.

Comment: I have created a fresh project, with the three models you defined and imported the data into two separate tables - - 'colors' and 'genotypes'.

Comment: Any pointers on making a drop down selecting one item from a given table and correlating it with another item from the other table? Sorry to be a pain. If you want to just point me at the resource explaining, I can try to figure it out myself.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a resource for your case so here's a pointer: https://gist.github.com/DiegoSalazar/7490062

Answer (score 0):

Right now my migration reads as follows:

```
class CreateColors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :colors do |t|
      t.string :angora_color
      t.string :genotype
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```